# Cordova local ajax request error

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, laravel

I'm trying to retrieve informations from PHP script on localhost

`app.js` on Cordova application :

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8000/locations';

$.ajax({
   url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      contentType: "application/json",
      async: true,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function(resp){
          console.log(resp);
      },
      error: function(err) {}
});
```

and the php code (with Laravel framwork)

```
return Location::all()->toJson();
```

I have this error

> Refused to load the script
>   'http://localhost:8000/locations?callback=jQuery21309354114597663283_1431278135791&_=1431278135792'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'".
>   Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is
>   used as a fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add policies to your Cordova app.

http://content-security-policy.com/

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/

Second link is exactly what you need, article is well written I can quote only:

> https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js in the context of this page’s
>   origin. We trust that code, but we can’t expect the browser to figure
>   out on it’s own that code from apis.google.com is awesome, while code
>   from apis.evil.example.com probably isn’t. The browser happily
>   downloads and executes any code a page requests, regardless of source.
>
> Instead of blindly trusting everything that a server delivers, CSP
>   defines the Content-Security-Policy HTTP header that allows you to
>   create a whitelist of sources of trusted content, and instructs the
>   browser to only execute or render resources from those sources. Even
>   if an attacker can find a hole through which to inject script, the
>   script won’t match the whitelist, and therefore won’t be executed.

Answer (score 1):

I just added this in the head tag

```
<access origin="*" />
```

and it works !